# class attribute doesnt work properly (python)

Tags: python

While trying to come up with a Hand class for a card game
I encountered a strange behavior from an attribute

if I try to set `self.number` as seen below it wont show the proper output
but if I make the same argument through a function `total()` it works properly

my question is: why does the attribute `self.number` not getting the value of `len(self.cards)`?

```
class Hand (object):

def __init__(self,number=0,cards=[]):

    self.cards=cards

    self.number=len(self.cards)

def total(self):
    return len(self.cards)

hand=Hand()
hand.cards.append(9)

print hand.cards
print len(hand.cards)
print hand.number
print hand.total()

output:
[9]
1
0    #I want this to be equal to 1
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute `self.number` is set at instantiation, use a property instead.

```
class Hand (object):
    def __init__(self, cards=None):
        self.cards = cards or []

    @property
    def number(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def total(self):
        return len(self.cards)
```

Comment: so for all a: __init__(a):  self.a=a are only checked and used during initiation
thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Jared the `@property` decorator just saves time & effort by, among other things, automatically giving me `set` and `get` commands, is that right? One could achieve the same by defining aspects of `property` by hand? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick: The @property decorator makes the method it decorates into a getter. Users of the class will be able to access `number` as if it were an attribute. To make a setter, you decorate the setter method with `@attribute_name.setter` (in this case it would be `@number.setter`).

Comment: There's some info about how `@property` is implemented [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

Answer (score 2):

Setting an instance variable to an expression does not create a binding between the inputs of that expression and the value of the instance variable. In other terms, setting `self.number` to `len(self.cards)` does not mean that `self.number` will get updated whenever you update `self.cards`.

Your program is functioning properly: When you create your object, `len(self.cards)` is 0, so `self.number` gets set to 0. When you change `hand.cards`, there are no statements changing `self.number`, so it stays 0.

The proper way to make your `self.number` attribute update is to use a [getter-setter pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) in order to make sure that `self.number` changes whenever `self.cards` changes.

The Pythonic way to create a getter-setter pair is to use the [`@property` decorator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

In your case, you could do it like this:

```
class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, number = 0, cards = None):
        self.cards = cards or []

    @property
    def number(self):
        return len(self.cards)
```

This way, even though it looks to anyone uses your class that they are reading an attribute, what actually happens under the hood is that the `number()` method gets called and correctly computes the current length of `self.cards`.